# Отображение всех данных через class

Tags: javascript

Объявленные в js сотрудники должны появляться в HTML все один за одним, а отображается только последний.

```js
'use strict';

class Worker {
    constructor(name,city,age,contractDate,standing,salary){
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
        this.contractDate = contractDate;
        this.standing = standing;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
    print(){
      let report = document.getElementById('report');
      report.innerHTML = `
        Имя: ${this.name} <br>
        Город: ${this.city} <br> 
        Возраст: ${this.age} <br>
        Дата контракта: ${this.contractDate} <br>
        Стаж: ${this.standing} <br>
        Оклад: ${this.salary} <br>
        Уволен <input type="checkbox">
`;
    }
}

let worker1 = new Worker('Александр', 'Минск', 32, '15.08.2018', '???','1000USD');
let worker2 = new Worker('John', 'Vilnius', 35, '02.11.2017', '???', '800USD');

worker1.print();
worker2.print();
```

```html
<p id="report"></p>
```

Comment: innerHTML = проблема здесь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы переназначаете, а надо добавлять.

```
  report.innerHTML += `
    Имя: ${this.name} <br>
    Город: ${this.city} <br> 
    Возраст: ${this.age} <br>
    Дата контракта: ${this.contractDate} <br>
    Стаж: ${this.standing} <br>
    Оклад: ${this.salary} <br>
    Уволен <input type="checkbox"> <br>
  `;
```